# angular call controller function inside directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i am working on a mini contacts list and i am trying ot achieve a drag and drop effect. Right now i have a controller that brings me data from a DB and looks like this.

```
Index.controller('cIndex', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function() {
        $http.get('php/contacts.php').success(function(data) {
            $scope.jsonContactsList = data;
            $scope.jsonContactsDetail = [];
        });
    };
    $scope.init();

    $scope.listdetail = function(index) {
        alert(index);
    };
});
```

And this controller adds a list of contacts on the screen. I want to make that when i drag an item from the list and drop it outside the list, the item disapears from the list and appears as a detailed div about that specific contact.

Now i have 2 directives, 1 that makes the drag effect and 1 that makes the drop effect and they look like this.

```
Index.directive('contactListDrag', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            var options = scope.$eval(attr.contactListDrag);
            elem.draggable(options);
        }
    };
});

Index.directive('contactListDrop', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.droppable({accept: '.contact-list-item'});
            elem.bind('drop', function(event, ui) {
                var id = parseInt($(ui.draggable).attr('id'), 10);
                $scope.listdetail(id);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Now inside the controller i have a function called listdetail, which i intend to make it change a line inside the jsonContactsList into jsonContactsDetail, but in order to do that, i need to call the listdetail function from the controller, inside the droppable contactListDrop directive.

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: $scope.listdetail(id); inside the second directive, does not trigger the  $scope.listdetail = function(index) {
        alert(index);
    };

from the controller

Answer (score 2):

I found out the fix on this, i had to use scope.listdetail(id); without the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

**$scope** is not available inside your directive.  You need to tell your directive about its parent.  Look at the section on **Understanding Transclusion and Scope** in the Angular docs here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

```
scope: {
    var: '='
}
```

You could also **scope.$emit** an event from your directive and listen for it in the controller by using **$scope.$on** - I think this is the better solution since your directive wouldn't be tied to a controller having a certain function.

Comment: Not correct, scope is available, if it is not isolated scope. He just had a typo :)